# How to combine row and column layout in flexdashboard in R?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am thinking of a lay out in which the column and row orientation is somehow combined.
The layout I am thinking of is something like this:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to render it with `runtime: shiny`? If it is a static HTML file you could create three columns and create column two and column three as separate rowwise pages in two separate files and embed them via an `iframe`.

Comment: Yes, I would like to render it with shiny.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to run with shiny, things can be done with:

````
---
title: "Title"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
library(shiny)
```

```{css}
.box-inside {border: 1px #e2e2e2 solid; height: 200px;}
.top-box {margin: -20px -10px 5px -10px;}
.right-rows {height: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto}
#section-column-2 .chart-shim.flowing-content-shim.flowing-content-container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Column {data-width=10%}
-------------------------------------
### A
```{r}

```

Column {.mid-col data-width=70%}
-------------------------------------
### B

<div class="top-box">

```{r}
column(
    3, class = "box-inside",
    "Add your content here"
)
```

```{r}
column(
    3, class = "box-inside",
    "Add your content here"
)
```

```{r}
column(
    3, class = "box-inside",
    "Add your content here"
)
```

```{r}
column(
    3, class = "box-inside",
    "Add your content here"
)
```

</div>

Column {data-width=20%}
-------------------------------------
### C
```{r}
fluidRow(
    class = "right-rows",
    "row content"
)
```

<hr style="margin: auto -8px;">

```{r}
fluidRow(
    class = "right-rows",
    "row content"
)
```
````

Replace `xx content` with your own components. You may want to learn a bit about how to [add UI to columns and rows](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html)

[image]